# document.getElementsByClassName in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made two alert messages using Bootstrap 3. Each alert is a **div** with class **alert**.

I'd like to add **fade** and **in** classes to each alert so that they fades when closing.

Why does the JS script below not work?  Thank you.

```
var alerts = document.getElementsByClassName("alert");
for (var i = 0; i < alerts.length; i++) {
  alerts[i].className += "fade in";
}
```

I tried using jQuery and that worked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.alert').addClass('fade in');
});
```

Faulty code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var alerts = document.getElementsByClassName("alert");
    for (var i = 0; i < alerts.length; i++) {
      alerts[i].className += "fade in";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    Message</div>
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    Message</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it already has a class, `alert`, and then you add more by just concatenating to the string

```
"alert" + "fade in" === "alertfade in";
```

note that you're not getting a space in there, and you could either do

```
alerts[i].className += " fade in";
```

which isn't a very good solution, or in modern browsers you can do

```
alerts[i].classList.add('fade');
alerts[i].classList.add('in');
```

Or write your function that does somewhat the same, there's a polyfill on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) that would do that for you.

Also note that you're trying to access the elements before they are available in the DOM, you either need to move the script tag or use a DOM ready handler, but most of all you need to open the console when something doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your script after the elements. You also need a space when adding your new classes `alerts[i].className += " fade in";`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    Message</div>
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    Message</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var alerts = document.getElementsByClassName("alert");
    for (var i = 0; i < alerts.length; i++) {
      alerts[i].className += " fade in";
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```